# On windows 10, how do I setup a VPN client so that all users can use it (i.e. available before login)

Tags: vpn, windows-10

On Windows XP, 7, 8, 8.1 you could tick a box that says 'Allow other users to use this VPN' when you initially connected the VPN.

This option is no longer available - how do I set the VPN to be available for connection on the Login screen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Old question but for anyone trying to find an answer there is a better solution via elevated powershell:

```
Add-VpnConnection -Name MY_VPN_NAME -ServerAddress MY_VPN_SERVER -AllUserConnection $true -SplitTunneling $true -AuthenticationMethod MSChapv2 -TunnelType Automatic -EncryptionLevel Required -PassThru
```

[Source](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28745579/Windows-10-VPN-connection-setup-allow-other-people-to-use-this-connection-not-working-Network-Sign-in-not-showing-on-logon-screen.html)

Comment: Maybe a change since this answer but I had to remove both $true variables as it was not recognised

Answer (score 1):

*CrayFishUK*, my experience for all **Windows XP/Vista/7/2008/8/2012/10** This will connect **VPN** as a **SYSTEM** user when system starts.

> 1. You will need to create a VPN connection
> 2. Save or not save credential it is not important.
> 3. Find a rasphone.pbk in %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk_hiddenPbk
> 4. More nice if you will copy it to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk or
>      attach to exist rasphone.pbk (it is text files)
> 5. Now you need to create scheduler task...

**Scheduler task:**

- Start after boot
- Program to start has credential to connect VPN

Code:

```
cmd /c rasdial VPNUSER VPNPASSWORD /PHONEBOOK:"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk" && route add 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.254
```

- You will need change the creator user to the **SYSTEM** user

I have add at the end:

```
route add 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.254
```

for exampe, how to auto add route when sucsesful connect VPN

> If you will need to reconnect VPN when it fails ask a new question and
>   I will help.
>
> By default VPN send all traffic through VPN, if you want to use routes You will need to turn off this future.

Answer (score 0):

A VPN config is stored as text in rasphone.pbk. The all-user copy of rasphone.pbk is located in the "all users" profile: on win11 pro the default is

```
c:\users\all users\microsoft\network\connections\pbk\rasphone.pbk
```

There are many ways you can add to or modify a text file. You can copy rasphone.pbk from your admin profile. You can copy and append from a text file: You can use WMI (or any Web-Based Enterprise Management controller), or RAS.exe or powershell -- which is a shell for things like RAS and WMI.

EAP data is stored as a blob in the file (CustomAuthData) Credentials are stored separately: the GUID referenced in the config file is used as a key to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Security\Cache. If you use certificate, make sure that it is stored in a store that the user has access to.

Rasphone.pbk is not "a vpn". It is a "phone book".  When you put your phone book entries in the global phone book, windows can see them before login.

Answer (score 0):

You CAN still setup a VPN for all users on Win10 and Win11 and you CAN still setup a VPN that to connect to a network (Network Sign in) before you login through the GUI. Microsoft have just made the interface a bit more convulted to get to it.
Click Start, then type Control Panel.
Click the **Network and Internet** heading, then select the **Network and Sharing Centre** heading.
Then select the **Setup a Connection or Network**.
Choose the option  **Connect to a workplace**.
Create a new connection, choose **Use my Internet Connect (VPN)**, then add in the details (i.e. VPN server IP address or host name, and a name for the connection).
Make sure you tick the option, **Allow other people to use this connection**.

[image]